# Play back of animation stops on last rendered image

Tags: rendering, animation

I have a simulation of a wreaking ball hitting some blocks. I click Animation and when it is completed animating and I click play to watch it, nothing happens. It just shows me the last rendered image in the animation.

Comment: did you make sure you are exporting it somewhere? if you arent then make sure to export in a readible format and play it from the folder

Comment: could you expand on the question? what are your render settings? how are you playing back your animation? maybe a blend file would help us find an answer for your question.

Comment: Where are you pressing "play"? What happens if you press Ctrl F11?

Comment: I just changed some resolution around and a couple little things but I don't know how and where to save it?